# org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Just trying to deploy web service war file but could not make it using apache tomcat 7. I tried sample war file and it works fine just accesing from browser localhost:8080/sample so sure that my tomcat is well configured. just copying the war under webapps/ and deploy it but same message: description The requested resource is not available.
I am wondering if web service application shows another way to deploy it ??? 
here is a content of catalina.log file:

```
 4:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
4:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/APP] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 12, 2012 4:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Any idea ??

Comment: Look for errors above those lines, and also look for additional logs in catalina.2012-10-13.log.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your response, In fact am trying to resolve that error for two weeks. log file shows the same error message. That s why I am wondering if it could be the nature of the war file itself should be deployed in different way>

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. The catalina.out logged this log Message

Apr 17, 2013 5:14:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Error listenerStart

The error is caused when a exception is thrown while the server is starting.

To figure out what is causing the you should look at **localhost.log** (in the same directory as catalina.out) not catalina.out, you should be able to see the exception that caused the error

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error by adding a logging.properties file in your WEB-INF/classes folder with the following contents:

> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Comment: Thanks Nickmancol for the hint. I have already added the file before and seems the same message in the log file. But I could add other line shown as: **SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.20 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.24** could be a the main reason for deploying the war file. I could already deploy other war files but the APP.war one. ??

Comment: As far as I know this is a library which is used to improve performance (on production systems) and not essential for deploying projects. Besides, adding the logging.properties file in the WEB-INF/classes folder has no noticed effect to check the error on the log file. I see it is the same line output.

Comment: Well if that doesn't worked, you should check the tomcat doc about logging http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html and maybe this post about the infaous error http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/

Comment: I had already checked the documentation and still looking for new lines in the log files but still the same. Am not using log4j as was presented in the links